# A tangent to a differentiable function $f$ cannot cross it again given $f'$ is injective

Tags: calculus

Given $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ a differentiable function on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f'$ is injective and given a tangent at $(x_0,f(x_0))$, prove that the tangent doesn't cross $f$ at any other point.

My reasoning is that $f$ must be convex but not sure how to use it.

Comment: Why do you think $f$ must be convex?

Comment: @mrsamy It could be strictly convex or strictly concave, but these are the only two possibilities.

Comment: $x\mapsto -x^2$ isn't convex, yet its derivative is an injective function.

Comment: In fact, $f$ must be strictly convex (or concave), therefore $f(x)>f(y)+f'(y)(x-y)$ for all $x\neq y$ (or $f(x)<f(y)+...$).

Comment: @mrsamy I meant convex/concave if $f'$ is increasing / if $f'$ is decreasing (the cases are parallel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tangent at $(x_0,f(x_0))$ has the equation

$$y=f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0).$$

Now suppose that there is $x_1$ such that $x_1 \ne x_0$ and

$$f(x_1)=f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x_1-x_0).$$

Then we have

$$ \frac{f(x_1)-f(x_0)}{x_1-x_0}=f'(x_0).$$

On the other hand ,the mean value theorem gives some $t$ between $x_1$ and $x_0$ such that $x_1 \ne t \ne x_0$ and

$$ \frac{f(x_1)-f(x_0)}{x_1-x_0}=f'(t).$$

Then we have $f'(x_0)=f'(t).$ But $f'$ is injective, hence $t=x_0,$ a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $f'(a)(b-a)+f(a) = f(b)$ with $a<b$ (meaning that the tangent intersects in the two points $a$ and $b$). By the mean value theorem we know that $f(b)-f(a) = f'(\xi)(b-a)$ for some $\xi$ strictly between $a$ and $b$. What conclusion can you then draw?